# How to concatenate data in XSL?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <value>A</value>
            <value>B</value>
            <value>C</value>
            <value>D</value>
            <value>E</value>
            <value>F</value>
        </level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

Guess I want to concatenate only the first three values in XSL in order to get ABC. How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the focus item is the level2 node, you can use a XSLT 1.0 sequence constructor like...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(value[1],value[2],value[3])" />
```

...or in XSLT 2.0...

```
<xsl:value-of select="for $i in 1 to 3 return value[$i]" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with one piece of XPath:

```
/root/level1/level2/value[position() &lt;= 3]/text()
```

To put that into an XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="root/level1/level2/value[position() &lt;= 3]/text()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Suppose I want to store the string in a hidden field. How do I do that?

Comment: Just put a `<xsl:variable name="myVar">..</xsl:variable>` round the `<xsl:copy-of` and you can then do whatever you need to with `$myVar`.

Answer (score 3):

**I. Here is a general and powerful way to produce the concatenation of any values given their (increasing) positions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPositions" select="'|1|2|3|'"/>

 <xsl:template match="value">
     <xsl:if test="contains($pPositions, concat('|',position(),'|'))">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <value>A</value>
            <value>B</value>
            <value>C</value>
            <value>D</value>
            <value>E</value>
            <value>F</value>
        </level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
ABC
```

**Should we wish the concatenation of the 1st, 3rd and 6th `value` elements values, we just provide a corresponding `$pPositions` parameter**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pPositions" select="'|1|3|6|'"/>
```

**and the same, unchanged XSLT code now produces the wanted**:

```
ACF
```

---

**II. Things become more interesting if we have any (not necessarily increasing) sequence of positions:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPositions">
  <p>4</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>3</p>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vPositions" select=
      "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pPositions']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="."/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vPositions/p">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vDoc/*/*/*/value[position()=current()]"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above) we get the wanted, correct result:**

```
DAC
```

---

**III. This is trivial in XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPositions" as="xs:integer*" select="4,1,3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of separator="" select=
   "for $n in $pPositions
     return
        /*/*/*/value[$n]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//level2/string-join(value[position() &lt; 4] , '')" />
```

I hope this could help.